# Copying all tr elements from one table to another table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am new to jQuery so I need help to copy all the tr elements (along with their `<td>` elements) of one table to another table which already has some `<tr>`s. The two tables have the same columns.

Comment: You should use clone() jquery method to copy of the set of matched element.

Comment: I have a table with <thead> and <tbody>. To get the <tr> elements I use $("tbl tbody").children() (or $("tbld tbody tr")) but it only returns the <td> element of the first <tr> ! I need all the <tr> tags such as <tr><td> Hello <td><tr> <tr><td> salute <td><tr>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$('#table1').html($('#table2').html());
```

Or if you want to copy the content you can append it like this:

```
$('#table1').html($('#table1').html() + $('#table2').html());
```

Or you can use each with the selected tr.

Comment: Thanks but it will copy the <thead> too